# Programa que calcula IMC

Tags: javascript, html5

Pessoal estou criando um programa em javascript que calcula IMC, existem pacientes fixos que já vem com seu dados preenchidos e eu estou colocando a opção de adicionar mais pacientes.
O problema é quando se cria um novo paciente pois, não esta preenchendo uma parte da tabela "classificação"
tentei criar uma função com "if" mas esta retornando "undefined", não sei mais o que fazer.

A função está dentro de um for

```
function classe () {
    if (imc) {

        var tdClass = paciente.querySelector(".info-class")
        tdClass.textContent = "Teste";
    }

    return;
}

var executa = classe();
```

Aqui criei outra fução para pegar os dados do paciente

```
    var paciente = {

        nome: form.nome.value,
        peso: form.peso.value,
        altura: form.altura.value,
        gordura: form.gordura.value,
        imc: calculaImc(form.peso.value, form.altura.value),
        classificaocao: classe()
        
    }
    
    return paciente;
};

E essa outra para adicionar os novos paciente a tabela

    function montaTr (paciente){

    var pacienteTr = document.createElement("tr");
    pacienteTr.classList.add("paciente");
    
    pacienteTr.appendChild(montaTd(paciente.nome, "info-nome"));
    pacienteTr.appendChild(montaTd(paciente.peso, "info-peso"));
    pacienteTr.appendChild(montaTd(paciente.altura,"info-altura"));
    pacienteTr.appendChild(montaTd(paciente.gordura, "info-gordura"));
    pacienteTr.appendChild(montaTd(paciente.imc, "info-imc"));
    pacienteTr.appendChild(montaTd(paciente.classificaocao, "info-class"));

    return pacienteTr;
};
```

Comment: Coloca o código todo, ajuda. Inclusive a parte html.

Answer (score 0):

**Para que a classificação seja de acordo com imc:**

Em var paciente `classificacao: classe(imc)`

**O loop for**

```
    var pacientes = document.querySelectorAll(".paciente");

    for (var i = 0; i < pacientes.length; i++) {
                
        var paciente = pacientes[i];
        
        var tdPeso = paciente.querySelector(".info-peso");
        var peso = tdPeso.textContent;
        
        var tdAltura = paciente.querySelector(".info-altura");
        var altura = tdAltura.textContent;
        
        var tdImc = paciente.querySelector(".info-imc"); 
         
        tdImc.textContent = calculaImc(peso,altura);
                        
        var tdClass = paciente.querySelector(".info-class");
                               
        tdClass.textContent = classe(imc); 
                            
    }
```

**A função classe**

```
function classe (valorIMC){

        if (valorIMC<18.5){
            classificacao="Magreza";
        }else if (valorIMC<24.9){
            classificacao="Normal";
        }else if (valorIMC<29.9){
            classificacao="Sobrepeso";
        }else{
            classificacao="Obesidade";
        }

    return classificacao;
}
```

Comment: amigo na verdade eu não quero que a classificação seja fornecida pelo usuário e sim preenchida automaticamente de acordo com o imc, por exemplo imc 18.5 - 24.9 classificação Adequado